# Help with static::$value

Tags: php, static, php-5.3

I have been see this come up alot i think it has todo with late static binding but whats the point of doing it this way.

```
class {
    public static $name = array();

    function something() {
        static::$name;
    }
}
```

over

```
class {
    public static $name = array();

    function something() {
        self::$name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self::$name` in the parent class will *always* refer to the parent class' property whereas `static::$name` in the parent class will refer to the property of the runtime class.

For example

```
class A
{
    protected static $foo = 'foo';

    public static function getSelfFoo()
    {
        return self::$foo;
    }

    public static function getStaticFoo()
    {
        return static::$foo;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected static $foo = 'bar';
}

echo A::getSelfFoo(); // 'foo'
echo A::getStaticFoo(); // 'foo'

echo B::getSelfFoo(); // 'foo'
echo B::getStaticFoo(); // 'bar'
```

Comment: Thank Phil that helped, so is it bad to use static::$name even if the class will never have a child??

Comment: @ChrisR Nope. The use of `static` or `self` would entirely depend on how you wanted the property or method accessed

Answer (score 0):

It matters if you create a subclass of your class. In your first example, the `something` function will refer to the `$name` variable on the subclass. In your second example it will refer to the `$name` variable on the base class.